# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using rails 3 + devise. When a user signs up and there is an error. The app is redirecting to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users
```

Showing the error messages, but in the log I see the following:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jul 11 20:22:19 -0700 2011
  Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create my account", "fb_access_token"=>"XXXXX", "authenticity_token"=>"fWd/XXXX=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "lname"=>"XXXX", "fname"=>"XXXX", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"XXXX-inc.com"}, "fb_uuid"=>"312312"}
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'brett@companyline-inc.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/unauthorized (11.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 22.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jul 11 20:22:20 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users"):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

**routes.rb:**

```
  # OmniAuth - for FB Connect
  match '/users/auth/facebook/callback' => 'authentications#create'

  # Devise
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Why the actionController error?

Comment: Show the RegistrationsController and the form for the `new` action in this controller please.

Answer (score 0):

What does `rake routes` show you? The order in which you place your routes matters also, since the Rails router picks the first route it matches.

Hope this helps!